# Gateway function corrupting input from matlab to c++ mex program

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I'm testing passing a sparse matrix from matlab to a c++ mex-program. When I return the variables I send in the arrays get corruptet. Do you know how to fix this?

```
    #include "mex.h"

    void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const   mxArray *prhs[]){



int M = 0, N = 0, nz = 0, *I = NULL, *J = NULL;
float *val = NULL;
float *x;
float *rhs;



M = (int)mxGetM (prhs[0]);
N = (int)mxGetN (prhs[0]);
nz = (int)mxGetNzmax (prhs[0]);
val = (float *)mxGetPr (prhs[0]);
I = (int *)mxGetIr (prhs[0]);
J = (int *)mxGetJc (prhs[0]);
rhs = (float *)mxGetData(prhs[1]);//b-vec
plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(N, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
x = (float *)mxGetData(plhs[0]);
//DisplayMatrix("Input", rhs, N, 1);

//Test
for(int i = 0; i<M; i++){
    x[i] = val[i];
}
printf("%d",M);
}
```

So when making a sparse five diagonal matrix and calling this function with x=mf(A,b); the entries in the returned x is blown up from e.g. 0.3 to
01e38. Do you know why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The range of valid values in `val` is from `0` to `nz-1` (at most). You are copying `M` values. Also, note that the valid range for `x` is from `0` to `N-1` - but this may well not be a problem if your `A` is square.

Also, note that if `A` is sparse, it cannot possibly contain values of type `float` since MATLAB supports only `double` and `logical` for sparse. You should make `val` be of type `double const *`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Edric! This solves the problem!

I changed the initialization of val to

```
    double const *val = NULL;
```

and the input to:

```
    val = (double const *)mxGetPr (prhs[0]);
```

Great!